# Access array in php passed through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass an associative array through Ajax to a php as follows

```
var arr={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3};
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'data.php',
    data:arr,
});
```

In php I want to loop over all the elements of the array somewhat as below

```
 $data=$_POST;
 foreach($data as $k=>$v)
 {
     echo $k.'='.$v;
 }
```

Can someone help me in this regard.

Comment: What's the problem with above code?

Comment: what u have done is correct and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this  by

```
var newarr = JSON.stringify(arr);
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'data.php',
    data:{dat:newarr} ,
});
```

and in php

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['dat']);
 foreach($data as $a){
     echo $a;
  }
```

---

you can also use `serializeArray()`

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'data.php',
    data:{dat: $(arr).serializeArray()} ,
});
```

Then `$_POST['data']` will be an array

Comment: $_POST['data'] is not accessing the array

Comment: why is it json encoded ? any ways his object will be received as post array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

[From -PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

This did the job

```
data:{dat:arr}
```

on the jquery and

```
$data=$_REQUEST['dat']
```

on php

Comment: That doesn't explain why you couldn't iterate over `$_POST` before.